# Mysql select records having difference of hours

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
ID  DATE

1   2013-08-12 08:59:16
2   2013-08-13 08:59:16
3   2013-08-14 08:59:16
4   2013-08-17 08:59:16
```

I want to select those records where difference of dates is within 36 hours of each other, *not* the current date

In the example above, the dates on the 12th and 13th is one case and 13th and 14th is another.

Sorry if question not clear, but its for purely mysql

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work around giving advice, it works around giving answers to **specific problems**. Currently your question is just a statement of what you're trying to achieve, which doesn't fit with SO's [guidelines for a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: please show us your code and where you are facing problem...

Comment: How I'd do it is I'd loop through every record, and per record check the table again for all the next records (with a higher id) and add this to a var/array. This does require many query's, but it should work. Perhaps there is a more efficiënt way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery for this.  The following gets any row within 36 hours of the preceding or next row:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id <> t.id and
                    t2.date between t.date - interval 36 hour and t.date + interval 36 hour
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID id1,
  t1.`date` date1,
  t2.ID id2,
  t2.`date` date2
FROM
  tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON
    t1.id!=t2.id AND
    t2.`date` BETWEEN t1.`date` AND t1.`date`+ INTERVAL 36 HOUR
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a71e/1).

Comment: your query also fetches correct result, the other one was more precise what i wanted to do next pertaining to the selected records, i do appreciate your time , thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this *(small edit: OP mentioned the sql-only part after my answer)*:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT id,date FROM tablename");

while($thisRow= $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $nextQuery = "SELECT id,date FROM tablename 
                  WHERE date>".$thisRow['date']." AND date<=".strtotime($thisRow['date']."+ 1 day")."
                  LIMIT 1";
    $next= connection->query($nextQuery);
    if($next->num_rows!==0){
        /* This line and the next line match
           $thisRow has info about current line
           $fetchNext has info about next line */
        $fetchNext = $next->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for later mention of mysql part, as this is my first post , i thought putting a mysql tag would be enough

Comment: myeah, Some people tag mysql and then proceed to use php. They're commonly used. No biggy